# $G$ contains at least $r(p-1)$ elements of order $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, normal-subgroups

Suppose a group $G$ has $r$ distinct subgroups of prime order $p$. Show that $G$ contains at least $r(p-1)$ elements of order $p$.

Aside: I know how to use this to prove that a group of order $56$ has a proper normal subgroup.

Comment: In general, If there is $k$ cylic subgroup of $n$ then there are $k\phi(n)$  elements of order $n$ in $G$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Suppose G is a group, and p is prime. Then the number of elements of G of order p is multiple of p-1.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1042085/suppose-g-is-a-group-and-p-is-prime-then-the-number-of-elements-of-g-of-order)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, note that the subgroups of prime order $p$ must be cyclic (why?). Which means that every element in them apart from $e$ is of order $p$. And for another fact, notice that two distinct subgroups of order $p$ can't have anything apart from $e$ in common, otherwise they wouldn't be distinct. Which means we have $r(p-1)$ such elements of order $p$ ($p-1$ because we're excluding $e$).

Answer (score 3):

IF $\;P,Q\;$ are two *different* subgroups of order $\;p\;$ , then clearly $\;P\cap Q=\{1\}\;$ (why?), and from here the claim, as there are $\;p-1\;$ elements of order $\;p\;$ in each such subgroup.

Comment: It seems contradictory to say "then *clearly*..." and ask the reader why. =)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff It's my way to direct him to think simple and not messy.