# Find number of elements of order $p$ in group $G$ where $p$ is prime and $G$ has $m$ subgroups of order $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Find the number of elements of order $p$ in group $G$, where $p$ is prime and $G$ has $m$ subgroups of order $p$.

[Suppose G is a group, and p is prime. Then the number of elements of G of order p is multiple of p-1.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1042085/suppose-g-is-a-group-and-p-is-prime-then-the-number-of-elements-of-g-of-order) is an equivalent problem to this, but it was closed (also I have a more specific question).

**The problem**

Suppose that a finite group $G$ has exactly $m$ subgroups of order $p$, where $p$ is a prime. Show that the number of elements of order $p$ in $G$ is $m(p-1)$.

**My solution**

Let $H_i, 1 \leq i \leq m$, be every subgroup with order $p$ in $G$.

*Theorem:*

> If $G$ is a group whose order is a prime $p$, then it is isomorphic to $C_p$
> (the cyclic group of order $p$).

Thus every $H_i$ is isomorphic to $C_p$.

Every cyclic group contains its generating element (of order $p$) exactly once, thus there must be at least $m$ elements in $G$ which has order $p$.

And that's as close as I can get to a solution.

Comment: *Hint:* If $i\ne j$, then $H_i\cap H_j=\{e_G\}$ and $H_i\setminus\{e_G\}$ has cardinality $=p-1$.

Comment: A cyclic group does not have **a** generator. It has *several* elements that can play that part. A group of prime order $p$ has exactly $p-1$ elements that can be considered "its generator". For instance, if $g$ is a generator of $C_3$, then $g^2$ is too, because $g=g^3g=g^4=(g^2)^2$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli, oh yeah, you're right. The reason it's $p-1$ in this case is because $p$ is prime and thus coprime to everything below $p$, yes? With that realisation the solution seems simple.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I wrote a solution, could you check it for me if you'd like to see if it is correct before I tick it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Suppose G is a group, and p is prime. Then the number of elements of G of order p is multiple of p-1.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1042085/suppose-g-is-a-group-and-p-is-prime-then-the-number-of-elements-of-g-of-order)

Answer (score 6):

Two subgroups of order $p$ are either equal or have trivial intersection.

Every nontrivial element in a subgroup of order $p$ has order $p$.

Each subgroup of order $p$ has $p-1$ elements of order $p$.

Every element of order $p$ belongs to a subgroup of order $p$.

Therefore, the number of elements of order $p$ is $m(p-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is almost correct, however there is a fault in my reasoning:

A cyclic group of order $n$ doesn't have just 1 generator, it has $\phi(n)$ generators where $\phi(n)$ is Euler's phi function. Or in other words: The amount of numbers which are coprime to the order of the cyclic group is equal to the amount of generators for that cyclic group.

Since $p$ is prime we have $p-1$ such numbers, thus we have $m(p-1)$  such elements in $G$.

Comment: For a group of prime order, *Lagrange's theorem* is enough to prove any element $\ne e$ in the group is a generator.

Comment: You need to use awllower's hint.